# Force Gmail to always pop out the compose window

Tags: gmail

I dislike the compose window anchored to the side of my Gmail window. Is there a way to force Gmail to default to the pop-out window without having to select it with every email?

Comment: At the moment, holding `shift` while clicking the Reply button does this.

Answer (score 9):

You can press shift when clicking compose. Would be good if you didn't even need to do that though.

Comment: This works also when clicking on the _Reply_ button.

Comment: On Reply, this fails (does nothing) if a regular reply is already open.

Answer (score 6):

In the lower right hand corner of the compose window, click the little triangle to see more options.  Click the Default to full-screen option.

There does not seem to be a way to may the reply button always go to pop out window though.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; Molly wants pop-out windows for replies.  This answer tells you how to take an **already** popped-out compose window and make it full screen by default.   The "default to full-screen" option is also available only on new Compose windows, not on replies that have been popped-out.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the new compose feature do the following:

- Click compose
- Look for the link "Try out the new compose experience" it is on the same line as send/save now/ discard/labels.
- Click through the demo screens and now you are set to always use the new compose pop out feature.

To go back tot he old style of compose:

- Click compose
- In the lower right corner of the pop out window is a small menu next to the trashcan.
- The first item in the menu is "switch back to the old compose"

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve your issue is to switch to the old Gmail interface using the browser extension [Retro Compose](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/retro-compose-for-gmail/npjkmbechijncoapeeifgfhcjkcandgk/) (Chrome), [Old Compose](http://oldcompose.com/) (Chrome+Firefox), or [Fix Compose for Gmail](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fix-compose-for-gmail%C2%AE-to/hpoidnelefpoofhdioielagfklahfcjg/):

[image]

Comment: The link to Retro Compose is broken.   Google took me [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/old-compose-better-compos/fcnoahpalppomkbilmlkhiimjfmpmgpk).   Unfortunately, I installed this but it didn't work (in numerous ways).

Comment: All of the links in the answer are now broken.